# 2-column flexible layout with max-width on columns

Tags: layout, css

I need to create a 2-column layout like this:

When page width is big (> 1000px), left column has 600px and the right one fills all remaining space.

When page width is less, the right column has 400px and the left column shrinks to fit.

How can I achieve this with CSS?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables - Grid system - probably will do much more than you need - just setup what you need. Otherwise what Jonathan de M. said will do the job.